# Ayuda con Socket y archivos en Java

Tags: java, socket

verán, estoy haciendo este ejercicio...

Crear un programa cliente servidor donde un cliente solicite al servidor un archivo y este se lo envíe al cliente para posteriormente imprimirlo en pantalla.

El problema que tengo es que no puedo pasar el contenido del archivo, si cree el archivo del lado del cliente, pero no se pasa el contenido del archivo del servidor :(

Dejo código del Servidor...

```
package socket6;
import static java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType.C;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Socket6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket servidor=new ServerSocket(4500);
        Socket cliente=servidor.accept();

        FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream("C:\\archivoservidor.txt");
        byte b[]=new byte[20002];
        file.read(b,0,b.length);
        OutputStream out=cliente.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Socket6.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

}
```

Dejo el código del Cliente...

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Cliente {
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        byte []b=new byte[20002];
        Socket cliente=new Socket("localhost",4500);
        InputStream in=cliente.getInputStream();

        FileOutputStream file=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Palomita\\Documents\\Programacion web\\Sockets\\archivocliente.txt");
        in.read(b,0,b.length);
        file.write(b,0,b.length);

        File archivo = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        archivo = new File ("C:\\Users\\Palomita\\Documents\\Programacion web\\Sockets\\archivocliente.txt");
        fr = new FileReader (archivo);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String linea;
        while((linea=br.readLine())!=null)
            System.out.println(linea);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, y una disculpa, soy nueva en esto de Java jeje :D

Answer (score 1):

hay muchos problemas con tu codigo. empezemos por el lado del Servidor:

> ```
> ...
> ServerSocket servidor=new ServerSocket(4500);
> Socket cliente=servidor.accept();
> FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream("C:\\archivoservidor.txt");
> byte b[]=new byte[20002];
> ```

Aqui vemos un problema `byte b[]=new byte[20002];` este "*buffer*" de bytes es Exesivo o al contrario es insuficiente. no es recomendable hacer un "*buffer*" de memoria tan grande sin conocimiento de cuanto realmente se va a necesitar, en este caso se recomienda y se utilizara [Files.readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)(en ingles)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path))

[recomendacion sobre el Tamaño del buffer(en ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236861/how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-buffer-size-when-using-fileinputstream)

> ```
> file.read(b,0,b.length);
>     OutputStream out=cliente.getOutputStream();
> } catch (IOException ex) {
>     Logger.getLogger(Socket6.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
> }
> }
> }
> ```

y eso es todo! donde Envia los datos al `out`? por tanto aqui el problema es: no se esta transmitiendo **NADA** debemos enviar los bytes que estan en `b` hacia `out` mediante `out.write()` 
otro problema **GRAVE** es que no se estan cerrando los Streams! no cierras el Stream de lectura `file` ni el socket (ya sea el de servidor o el Cliente!)

por tanto un codigo Mejorado Y correcto seria:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Socket6 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
//try con recursos (try con autoclose) ver link
    try (ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(4500)) {
        try (Socket SocketCliente = servidor.accept()) {
            byte filebytes[] = null;
            try {
                //se lee TODOS los bytes del archivo a un Byte Array. 
                filebytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("archivoservidor.txt"));
            } catch (IOException fileex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Socket6.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error en la Lectura del archivo Datos", fileex);
            }
            //si filebytes es nulo significa que la lectura fallo o el archivo esta vacio! 
            if (filebytes != null) {
                //el paso anterior puede tardar mucho necesitamos asegurar que el socket (cliente) aun este disponible(connectado)
                if (!SocketCliente.isClosed() && SocketCliente.isConnected()) {
                    try {
                        OutputStream outstream = SocketCliente.getOutputStream();
                        //tomar los bytes y escribirlos al stream (NOTA esto puede que no Envie los datos para asegurar que se envien debemos usar Flush!
                        outstream.write(filebytes);
                        //flush (enviar los datos al cliente)
                        outstream.flush();
                    } catch (IOException outex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Socket6.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error en la Transmisión de Datos", outex);
                    }
                } else {
                    Logger.getLogger(Socket6.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "El Socket esta Cerrado o desconectado");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("done");
        //nota si usamos try with resource no necesitamos hacer close() 
        //PERO! si usamos un "try normal" debemos hacer SocketCliente.close() en el Finally Statement... de **este** try
        //SocketCliente.close();
        }//SocketCliente close implisito
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Socket6.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception con el Socket?", ex);
    }// servidor close implisito
    }

}
```

[try con recursos (try con autoclose)(en ingles)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

El Cliente posee errores en Similares, no cierras los Streams! y no haces Flush para mandar los datos al Archivo! en cada loop.

Ademas de esto, las lineas: `in.read(b,0,b.length);` y `file.write(b,0,b.length);` solo sucede 1 ves(no esta dentro de un loop). Osea si `20002` bytes no esta todos los datos del archivo solo guardas esos `20002` bytes y el resto del archivo? queda por fuera o viseversa. si el archivo es de 496 bytes (suponiendo es solo texto en ansii son 62 letras) el archivo va a tener datos invalidos (el resto de los bytes en 0 `\0`) por tanto el resultado puede ser incositente con lo esperado. para evitar eso debes usar loops. ver: [guia sobre loops(en ingles)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-java/)

y por tanto para que el cliente realize la funcion de forma correcta

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte readbytes[] = new byte[1000];//1000 aunque podriamos usar 4096
        //try with resources socket & inputsstream 
        try (Socket cliente = new Socket("localhost", 4500); InputStream in = cliente.getInputStream()) {
            //try with resourse for the file Write operation
            try (OutputStream FileToFill = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("archivocliente.txt"))) {
                //loop para lectura del archivo usamos un for para poder
                //declarar una variable & hacer la verificacion podriamos 
                //usar un While pero necesitariamos 1 variable extra.
                for (int read=-1;(read = in.read(readbytes)) >= 0;) {
                    //se llena los datos a guardar con los Bytes del socket
                    FileToFill.write(readbytes, 0, read);
                    //se imprimimen los bytes leidos 
                    //se asume que usa el mismo <CHARSET> de la PC & que los bytes representan texto
                    System.out.print(new String(readbytes, 0, read));
                    //se graban los bytes al archivo!
                    FileToFill.flush();
                }
            }//implisit file close. 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }//implisit Socket close & input close

    }
}
```